# Appcrash: How to delete a character in edittext by pressing delete button?

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext

The `edittext` have only one character limit, a delete button delete the character in edittext but the problem is when I pressed the delete btn in empty `edittext`. App becomes crash.

I have used below code but when I click on del btn in empty `edittext` , App crash.

```
del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String text = et1.getText().toString();
                        et1.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                    }
                });
```

This error is display in logcat.

```
IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Plz help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the problem is when I pressed the delete btn in empty edittext. App becomes crash.

Yes, because you are trying to do a `substring` of a null, that's why it crashes, to avoid it, just add an `if` condition before doing the action as follows :

```
del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      String text = et1.getText().toString();
      if(!text.isEmpty()) et1.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String text = et1.getText().toString();
                      if(!text.isEmpty())
                     {
                        et1.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                     }
```